# Google Ad Manager API - googleads library compatibility

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I am currently using googleads library https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib version 32.0.0, but I can successfully use 202308 version of GAM API and this is a bit confusing as the 202308 release was in 39.0.0. So how does it actually can work?

Is it some compatibility between googleads library and GAM API or can I just use any non deprecated version of the GAM API on any version on of the googleads library?

I have tried to use different GAM API versions with my old versioned googleads library. I expect to see an error due to outdated version of library but it actually works.